# How to place one item at end of Column without a wrapper Composable in Android Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a `Column` like this,

```
Column {
    Comopsable1()
    Comopsable2()
    Comopsable3()
}
```

I want `Composable1()` followed by `Composable2()` from the top.
But, I want to place `Comosable3()` at the bottom of the column.

Is there a way to do this without introducing a wrapper Composable for Composale3()?

My current code which works,

```
Column {
    Comopsable1()
    Comopsable2()
    Column(
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Bottom,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight(),
    ) {
        Comopsable3()
    }
}
```

Is there a way to remove the newly introduced `Column`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add a spacer and set it to have a weight of 1

```
Column {
    Composable1()
    Composable2()
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
    Composable3()
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Works as required.